# CSS3 effects with jQuery only works on chrome debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div object using jQuery and CSS3. But i am obtaining a weird behavior. Effect works on only chrome debug mode. Here is the code

```
var $s = $('#animateMePlease');
$s.css('transition-duration', 0+'ms');
$s.css({
opacity:0,
display:'block'
});
// debugger; // only works when i stop once code execution here, and release again
$s.css('transition-duration', d.duration+'ms');
$s.css({
opacity:1
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In newer browsers javascript doesn't update the style for each line, it tries to figure out when a redraw is really neccessary, so when you have two lines of javascript that change the same style within the same code block, only the last is generally executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery why not just use:

```
$('#animateMePlease').hide().fadeIn(d.duration);
```

and let jQuery handle the details in a browser-comaptible way - compare the [jQuery browser support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) with [the support for CSS3 transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

(Make sure that you actually have some number in `d.duration`)

### Update

After reading your comment I see why you don't want to use the standard jQuery way. Also if you are already using those transforms then you already depend on CSS3 support so using transition-duration is not an issue.

In that case you can change this:

```
$s.css({
  opacity: 1
});
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $s.css({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, 10);
```

so your code becomes:

```
var $s = $('#animateMePlease');
$s.css('transition-duration', 0 + 'ms');
$s.css({
  opacity: 0,
  display: 'block'
});
$s.css('transition-duration', d.duration + 'ms');
setTimeout(function () {
  $s.css({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, 10);
```

Adding a small timeout will make sure that the state that the DOM is in so far gets rendered before the opacity gets changed to 1.

See [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/rsp/pen/FfmnI/).

Comment: Thanks for the answering, i did not use 'fadeIn' instead of setting opacity because the css' are variable before and after the line '$s.css('transition-duration', d.duration+'ms');'. I will use there some scale, rotate and some position variables there.